# Why control is moving to a new command-line upon running node file?

Tags: node.js, express, server, backend, nodemon

I'm setting up a node.js server but its not running my server file. The code for the server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.status(200);
    res.send("Welcome to root URL of Server");
});
  
  
app.listen(PORT =>{
console.log("hello world" +PORT);
});
```

my json file:

```
{
  "name": "cp_viz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "none",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "none"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "none"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "none"
  ],
  "author": "none",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

whenever I run the command node server.js its moving to a new command line and not logging anything.

Comment: Could You provide Your output ? And How You start the server.js file ?

Comment: @MarioG8 I am not getting any output thats what I've said. I ran the nodemon server.js and node server.js to start the file but nothing happened.It jumped into a new line in the terminal instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("hello world" + " ", PORT);
});
```

Instead of :

```
app.listen(PORT =>{
console.log("hello world" +PORT);
});
```

Next install `nodemon` as a **development dependency** `npm install --save-dev nodemon`, and use this command in your **package.json** file =>

```
"dev": "nodemon server.js"
```

And run the `npm run dev` in your console ! And That's it !

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200);
  res.send("Welcome to root URL of Server");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("hello world" + " ", PORT);
});
```

Output **Visual Studio Code**

[image]

Output in the browser (**localhost**) `http://127.0.0.1:3000`:

[image]